# Set expiration time to sample django jwt token

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am trying to create a manual token and I would like to add expiration time.from here =>[Documentation](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creating_tokens_manually.html)

here=>

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken


refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

refresh.set_exp(lifetime=datetime.timedelta(days=10))
# refresh.lifetime = datetime.timedelta(days=10)

return Response ({            
                    'access': str(refresh.access_token),'refresh':str(refresh),"status":"success"
                    })
```

here is setting.py=>

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    # how long the original token is valid for
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=2),

    # allow refreshing of tokens
    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,

    # this is the maximum time AFTER the token was issued that
    # it can be refreshed.  exprired tokens can't be refreshed.
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=7),
}
```

but why this access token is expired after 5 min even I added 10 days? How can I add expiration time?

This method is created for authenticating with email and password. because default authentication is using user id and password. Is there any way to authenticate with email and password in drf sample jwt?

Answer (score 12):

Hey you can decide to use django-rest-framework-simplejwt library or rest_framework_jwt

For django-rest-framework-simplejwt use this way in your settings.py

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=10),
'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=20),
'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,

'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
'SIGNING_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,
'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
'AUDIENCE': None,
'ISSUER': None,

'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',

'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',
'TOKEN_USER_CLASS': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser',

'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=10),
'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=20),
}
```

For rest_framework_jwt use this way in your settings.py

```
JWT_AUTH = {
'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',

'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',

'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',

'JWT_SECRET_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,
'JWT_GET_USER_SECRET_KEY': None,
'JWT_PUBLIC_KEY': None,
'JWT_PRIVATE_KEY': None,
'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
'JWT_VERIFY': True,
'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
'JWT_LEEWAY': 0,
'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=10),
'JWT_AUDIENCE': None,
'JWT_ISSUER': None,

'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': False,
'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=30),

'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,

}
```

Comment: For visitors => from datetime import timedelta

Answer (score 7):

you have an error because you are updating the refresh time, you have to access the access_token

```
def get_tokens_for_user(user):

    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
    access_token = refresh.access_token
    access_token.set_exp(lifetime=timedelta(days=10))

    return {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(access_token),
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the lib Simple JWT, according to the [documentation](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#access-token-lifetime), in the settings, you have to use 'SIMPLE_JWT' instead of 'JWT_AUTH'.